# How to create, view and edit multiple lists?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a Windows Phone app where you should be able to create different lists, and add items to them. Is it possible to do that using MVVM?

I have not found a way to show list items in the current view in the app depending on witch list are selected. When the added lists shows up, I don't know how to mate them clickable, and show the items in the selected list

Thnx!

Comment: Please show your existing code.

Comment: I do not have any code for that, because i do not know how to organize it to make it work.

Comment: Lets say you have a class for Playlists, one for songs, and one for genre. The user shall be able to add New playlists, and add songs with a genre in it. 

I'm am pretty New to MVVM, so I know how to show a class on  page, but not how to enable the the content depend on what playlist is chosen. and sort the current playlist depending on genre.